# CMD Command to move all .srt to a previous named folder

Tags: cmd, command

I need a command to move every .srt file into their previously named folder:

So I need:

```
\Movie1\Movie1_spa.srt
\Movie2\Movie2_spa.srt
\Movie3\Movie3_spa.srt
```

Example folders:

```
\Movie1
\Movie2
\Movie3
```

I was trying with:

```
for %i in (*) do move "%i" "%~ni"
```

But this only move it has the exact name my .srt
But my .srt file have names like:

```
Movie1_spa.srt
Movie3_spa.srt
Movie3_spa.srt
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thx

Comment: For the example should work (not tested): `for %i in (*) do @for /F "eol=| delims=_" %j in ("%~ni") do move "%i" "%j\"` Everything up to the first underscore in file name or the entire file name on not containing an underscore at all is interpreted as folder name. Leading underscores like for a file named `__MyMovie.srt` are removed and `MyMovie` is assigned in this case to the loop variable `j`.